# Stop MediaPlayer 250ms from end of file

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm using speech recognition in an interactive mobile app with google speech to text.

When the AI talks back to you, I stop listening to cancel out the noise.

Right now, I'm using `onCompletedListener` to resume recognition at the end of a file, but it would be ideal to start just before the file ends to account for network latency and optimize response time.

Is there a way to watch `currentPosition` and trigger an event 250ms from the end of each file? They are not uniform in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to detect current position is by calling "MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()", so the only solution is to periodically check the position and check if "(MaxPosition - CurrentPosition)" is between 200-300ms. This means that you need to do this check each 50/75ms to be sure to remain in that range.

An improvement could be start to periodically check (as I explained above) ONLY after "MaxLength-250ms" from the beginning of "MediaPlayer.play()".

Obliviously if you allow Seeks in MediaPlayer, this timer should be changed according after each Seek.

Comment: Is there a way to play the audio in a while loop, or something like that, on a separate thread that doesn't bog down the app? Then perform the checks and react?

Comment: What would you recommend as a period check? Just a `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` function on a 50ms loop to check and react?

Comment: The best way is start a small "loop of checks" few Millis before the needed moment. In fact if you have a 5 minutes music, I don't think you want to do a check every 50ms for all this time, am I right? So the best could be start this loop at "maxLength-500ms" and then do it each 50ms starting from that moment until you reach "maxLength-250ms". The loop-check is not guaranteed to be executed exactly every 50ms, just for this I suggest to start a bit earlier and then doo a short loop.